# Ambiguity in Perceptron loss function (C. Bishop vs F. Rosenblatt)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, perceptron

> Bishop's Perceptron loss

On one hand, it is stated in equation 4.54 of Chris Bishop's book (pattern recognition and machine learning) that the loss function of perceptron algorithm is given by:

$${E_p}(\mathbf{w}) =  - \sum\limits_{n \in M} {{\mathbf{w}^T}{\phi _n}} {t_n}$$

where $M$ denotes the set of all misclassified data points.

> Original Perceptron loss

On the other hand, The loss function used in the original perceptron paper written by Frank Rosenblatt is given by ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)):

$${1 \over s}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^s {\left| {{d_j} - {y_j}\left( t \right)} \right|} $$
which when translated to the notation of Bishop's book is given by:

$${1 \over N}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\left| {{t_n} - {\mathbf{w}^T}{\phi _n}} \right|} $$
where $N$ denotes the set of all data points.

> My question

My question is that why Bishop's version of Perceptron loss is different from the original paper? Considering Bishop's book as a highly recognized book in machine learning field, can we call it Bishop's Perceptron?!

> Scikit-learn's implementation

By the way, it seems that Scikit-learn uses Bishop's version of Perceptron loss ([Scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_loss_functions.html)). It is apparent from the following formula and figure:

```
-np.minimum(xx, 0)
```

which for one sample reduces to:
$$ - \min \left( {0,{\mathbf{w}^T}{\phi _n}{t_n}} \right)$$

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the  Bishop's version by unearthing! the Rosenblatt's [1962 Principles of neurodynamics, Page 110](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015039846566;view=1up;seq=134) book, so the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)'s version must be the alternative one.

[image]

[image]

It is worth noting that the book also has a chapter on error back-propagation ([page 292](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015039846566;view=1up;seq=316)), which resembles the Wikipedia version, but I think it is not exactly the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your detailed and demanding response. I’m really surprised by the amount of search you did in order to fix the issue.

Comment: @pythinker My pleasure! I'm glad I could help. This detective stuff is fun ;)

Comment: I’m pleased to hear that you are interested in this type of questions. So I will try to pose more questions like this :)